# git checkout auto completion when specifying --git-dir or -C arguments

Tags: bash, git

Im not sure it is possible, but im trying to get auto completion for git (add & checkout) in bash (ubuntu 18.04) to work when not in a git version controlled directory. Ive tried using:

`me@home:~: git -C ~/my/path checkout <tab>` (from the home directory) but it just lists the files in the current directory instead of branch names.

Is it possible to get branch auto completion when specifying a git path (with -C arg) in bash?

Comment: It works for me; the completion is provided by Git itself, and I use version 2.27.

Comment: Thanks alot, I was on 2.17.1 and after upgrading to 2.27 it worked